# Could not find startup program <folder>\<filename>.p in PROPATH

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to run a procedure but nothing shows up because of an error in PROPATH.

**propath.p**

```
PROPATH = PROPATH + ",C:\var\ch\project\tools\testfolder".
```

**.propath**

```
<propathentry env="all" kind="src" path="\project\tools\testfolder" platform="all"/>
```

> Exception occured during launch Reason: Could not find startup program
>   .p in PROPATH.

Comment: How do you run the program? When is propath.p called? Can you check the PROPATH in the Scratch Editor?

Comment: I just run a procedure in the testfolder called test.p.

Comment: Try what Robert describes below in your Scratch Editor or Procedure Editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to get where your propath refers to :

   ```
   MESSAGE PROPATH VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
   ```
2. Check your path whether it's referenced in the PROPATH :

   ```
   MESSAGE SEARCH("test.p") VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
   ```

   It will show you the filepath if it does referenced in the PROPATH. If not found then it will returns ?.